# CrystalReports error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, web-config, crystal-reports-2010

I inherited a web app which I'm tasked with maintaining.  The application has a dozen or so crystal reports, but I couldn't open them (well, I -could- but they were mostly numeric in nature).

I installed this: http://scn.sap.com/people/coy.yonce/blog/2010/11/12/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2010-production-release-now-available

Then, I could open them properly.  I made the necessary adjustments to some of them, saved, and attempted to test locally.  Before installing crystal reports (above), I ran the application locally and it worked fine.

**The problem:** Now that I've installed it and made my changes (very minor stuff and only to the rpts, not to any aspx files), I'm getting this error:

**Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

**Source Error: [No relevant source lines]**

Here's what I have in Web.config pertaining to Crystal Reports:

```
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

The versions here match the version in the reference's properties.

There are no dlls in the bin folder beyond the application's own dll.

There are the following 'Crystal' related references: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, CrystalDecisions.Shared, CrystalDecisions.Web

I've researched the problem, and some say I need to add an ajax dll.  Which one?  Also, in what way does that relate?

This was supposed to be a tiny adjustment and it's turning into a big thing at this point.  Any help you are able to offer is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problemi is tied to `System.Web.Extensions` dll, it's not a Crystal Reports problem.

Try removing `System.Web.Extensions` line in web.config.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked beautifully.  Why was that causing the problem?

Comment: the error is about a web.extensions that is referenced in web.config but not available in the server,so it can't be loaded.this library was an extension in 3.5 framework, but no longer exist now,You could find it and install but, as i supposed..application didn't use it! I gave this answer because.. happened to me too!